# What happens when we change the value of a string in C++

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;
int main () {
  string str = "Hello";
  str = "Hello World";
  cout<<str<<endl;
}
```

How is the memory handled by the string?

Comment: `std::string` will automatically copy the string over into its own memory.

Comment: `std::string` will *possibly clear* up its old contents and copy the new string into it. (It will expand the memory storage used for storing the strings if need be) You should get some [good C++ books](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list) and read them.

Comment: @WhiZTiM how will it do so without changing its address.

Comment: @Espionage: The buffer address, e.g. `&s[0]`, changes when the `string` instance reallocates its internal buffer.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf Thanks I think I understand it, but there is still one more thing I am not sure of, what changes will be made in the memory stack of the `main ()` function to make this happen.

Comment: @MateenUlhaq thanks for the reply.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Re:

> **”** How is the memory handled by the string?

Automagically.

That means, among other things, that there's no way to give a `std::string`, an externally created buffer. So it's a bit inefficient. On the bright side, the `swap` requirements for `std::string` (as opposed to `std::vector`) means that it can use the **small buffer optimization**, where short strings are stored without dynamic allocation, which helps to improve efficiency.

Comment: Can you please give us a view of the memory stack.

Comment: @Espionage: I think by "memory stack" you mean "memory layout". There's not much to it. With the small buffer optimization the (very short) string is typically stored directly in the `std::string` instance. And otherwise that instance holds a pointer to a dynamically allocated buffer elsewhere.

Comment: What could be the length of a very short strings?

Comment: As much as fits in one or two pointer values' worth. For a 32-bit compiler that's not much, like 7 characters or so. For a 64-bit compiler it might be twice that.